# Leaving USA and returning while on a 6 month visa

Tags: visas, usa, australian-citizens

I am an Australian resident here in the USA with a valid 6-month visa which expires in March 2015. I am planning to go to Punta Cana in the Dominican Republic for a 7-day vacation. Will it be okay for me to return to the USA to complete my 6 month visa until March 2015?

Comment: What visa is that? If it's B1 / B2 then look at it, it has the number of entries printed on it.

Answer (score 3):

A US visa will show the allowed entries, either Single (S) or multiple (M), something like this:

[image]

So, the answer to your question is inside your passport, just check it.